# Parsing with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a xml file with this:

```
<name>Alberto</name>
<subname>Martín</subname>
<age>24</age>
```

I want parser it with NSXMLParser and save data it in:

```
NSString *name;
NSString *subname;
NSString *age;
```

To do it im using:

```
    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) 
                       elementName namespaceURI (NSString *) namespaceURI 
                           qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
                       attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {

if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
{
    if (!soapResults)
    {
        soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

    elementoEncontrado = YES;
}}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if (elementoEncontrado)
{
    [soapResults appendString: string];
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
                         didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                         namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                         qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
{
    name=soapResults;
}   
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subname"])
{
    subname=soapResults;
}   
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"age"])
{
    age=soapResults;
}


 NSLog(@"%@", name, subname, age);
```

The problem is that subname and age never appears...

Comment: all these line to parse a very simple xml? why not use a simpler library called TBXML (http://tbxml.co.uk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for all elements here, since you're only creating the NSMutableString for `name` elements.

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) 
                   elementName namespaceURI (NSString *) namespaceURI 
                       qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
                   attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        if (!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }

        elementoEncontrado = YES;
    }
}
```

and release / nil your `soapResults` here, as well as set your `elementoEncontrado` to `NO` here

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        // copy or retain this, unless ARC.
        name=soapResults;
    }   

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subname"])
    {
        subname=soapResults;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"age"])
    {
        age=soapResults;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", name, subname, age);
    [soapResults release];
    soapResults = nil;

    elementoEncontrado = NO;
}
```

Comment: Ok friend, thanks. To copy the NSString to another, which is the best form in this case? name= [copy soapResults] or  [name release]
   name = [NSString stringWthString: theName]??? or other form?

Comment: I think that name = [soapResults copy]; should work just fine. Again, if not under ARC remember to release those instances later.